# Problem with SerialPort in a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I made an application in C# which sends 11 byte of data to a serial port using:

```
            port = new SerialPort("COM1");
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
            port.WriteTimeout = 1000;
            port.Open();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[11];
            buffer[0] = 0;
            buffer[1] = 0;
            buffer[2] = 0;
            buffer[3] = 3;
            buffer[4] = 2;
            buffer[5] = 4;
            buffer[6] = 1;
            buffer[7] = 20;
            buffer[8] = 50;
            buffer[9] = 0;
            buffer[10] = 120;
            port.Write(buffer, 0, 11);
```

Then I wrote another application to test the previous one. I would like to check if the 11 bytes were correctly sent. In this application I use:

```
        using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1"))
        {
            // configure serial port
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.Open();

            for (; ; )
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[11];
                port.Read(b, 0, 11);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
                {
                    sb.Append(b[i]);
                    sb.Append(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
```

to receive bytes. The problem is that, after sending something like this:

```
0 0 0 3 2 4 1 20 50 0 120
```

I receive:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 2 1 4 20 50 0 120 0
```

Why does it happen? What kind of error is there in my code?
Thank you

Comment: If you watch the serial port with HyperTerminal, does it see the correct 11 bytes?

Comment: @mtrw I sent binary data and Hyper Terminal shows them with strange characters. Is there a way to convert them in a numeric format?

Comment: sorry I missed your question.  I don't know of a way to make HyperTerminal handle binary data, but tools like PortMon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) are useful for that situation.  Anyway, I'm glad your problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking the result from `port.Read()`. It returns the number of bytes *read*, not the number of bytes *requested*. The output loop then needs to use this result as the upper limit.

Although you've setup timeouts on the sending side, you'll also need them on the reader too.

Comment: I solved my problem. There are two ways. The first is what you described. The second is: register an handle to the event DataReceived and call Read with BytesToRead bytes.

Answer (score 1):

To check what happens on a serial connection on my pc i use two tools:

- [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/): A emulator that creates two serial ports on a pc which can communicate with each other. The only drawback i encountered, is that you should set for both a COM port below 10.
- [Free Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/index.html): It sniffs on a com port and can show every byte that runs over the line. The only drawback i encountered, is that it sometimes has problems to disconnect and will only start again after a restart of the whole pc. So if you start a session with it, be sure you don't disconnect or accidentally close the application before you close the connection within your testing application.